# s.tk/meta should point to Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mso-mse-split, s.tk

Since The Big Split happened, http://s.tk/meta should point to Meta Stack Exchange. However it points to Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Been reported on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229799/update-s-tk-meta-to-point-to-mse-instead-of-mso. I'm on it.

Comment: lol I didn't even know there was that url xD

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could get single letter domain names...

Comment: They should try and get sta.ck (Cook islands)